# Customize bootbox prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, bootbox

I want to customize `bootbox prompt` input box. I want add `clsss` attribute in `input` element.

I try this code

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Enter Mobile Number',
    placeholder: '8801XXXXXXXXX',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Submit'
        }
    },
    callback: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

I want to something like that

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Enter Mobile Number',
    placeholder: '8801XXXXXXXXX',
    class: 'only-number',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Submit'
        }
    },
    callback: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

**Update**

As per **Guruprasad Rao** answer I update my code. But class attribute add in `div` element not in `input` element.

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Enter Mobile Number',
    placeholder: '8801XXXXXXXXX',
    className: 'only-number',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Submit'
        }
    },
    callback: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

See my inspect element pic
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Well there is an option called `className` in `bootbox` which you can use to add `class` and once you add `class` try setting its `maxlength` as below:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Enter Mobile Number',
    placeholder: '8801XXXXXXXXX',
    className: 'only-number',
    buttons: {
        confirm: {
            label: 'Submit'
        }
    },
    callback: function(value) {
        console.log(value);
    })
});
```

Once this is initialized you can add `maxlength` attribute on `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('.only-number').attr('maxlength','13');
});
```

**UPDATE**

Remove `className` during initialization and add below code once initialized

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.bootbox-form').find('input').addClass('.only-number').attr('maxlength','13');
});
```

Comment: I try with your answer. but class add in modal div elements. But i want to add class in input elements. see my updated question pls

Comment: @Md.SahadatHossain Will there be only input through out or more than one?

Comment: I don't write any modal html. bootbox plugin generate modal html. you can see the modal html in inspect element pic in my question

Comment: prompt will be only one input

Answer (score 1):

If someone need fast solution only for `maxlength` and other attributes limitations:

```
bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'MyTitle',
    className: 'bootbox-custom-class',
    callback: function( input_value ) {
        console.log(input_value);
    },
}).on("shown.bs.modal", function( event ) {
    $('.bootbox-custom-class').find('.bootbox-input').attr('maxlength',5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class using jquery following the prompt did the job for me. Then we can play with the style of the input.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   bootbox.prompt({
    title: 'Some Title',
    inputType: 'textarea',
    callback: function(value) {}
    });
   $('.bootbox-input-textarea').addClass("your_class");
});
```